# Autoequivalence group from semiorthogonal decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Suppose we have a semiorthogonal decomposition $\mathcal{D} = \langle \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \rangle$, and suppose we know fully the autoequivalence groups $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{B})$. Then do we know $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{D})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For instance, if $D_n$ is the derived category of representations of a quiver with two vertices and $n$ arrows then $D$ has a semiorthogonal decomposition with two components equivalent to derived categories of the base field (so this does not depend on $n$) , but the connected component of the group of autoequivalences of $D_n$ is $\mathrm{PGL}_n$.

Comment: Thank you - I was just typing up an edit to my question where I was going to mention the case of certain index $1$ Fano threefolds with the SOD $D^b(X) = \langle D^b(C), \mathcal{U}, \mathcal{O}_X \rangle$. I suspect $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X))$ (Bondal-Orlov) and the autoequivalences of the SOD won't have much to do with each other either.

Comment: Or even $D^b(\mathbb{P}^n)$!

Comment: First, most SOD are not canonical (e.g., you can act by a line bundle twist and get another SOD), so to have a relation you need to restrict to the stabilizer of the SOD. Further, the stabilizer acts on the components, but it also acts on the gluing data, so there may be elements that act trivially on the components but not on the whole category (as in my example).

Comment: @Sasha, do you have a reference on group of auto-equivalences of $D_n$?

Comment: No, I don't, but this should be easy.